# Regular expression for simple patterns

Tags: python, regex

## Problem

I have an image dataset that describes different activities appearing in the particular images. Each image in the dataset is named as `<activity>_<num>`. For example, `educating_13.jpg`, `practicing_147.jpg`, etc.

Now I want to select images with same activity, say "cooking", and I decided to do this using `re` module in Python. The script I wrote is like

```
pattern = "^(\w+)_(\d+)$"
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    root, _ = os.path.splitext(filename)
    activity = re.match(pattern, root).group(1)
    if activity == "cooking":
        # do something
```

However, even though many images are successfully processed. It finally aborted with `AttributeError`. It seems that some of the images could not be matched with the specified pattern.

So do I make some mistake? Any input is appreciated.

EDIT:

By using exception mechanism in Python, it turns out that of almost 150 thousand images, there is a text file called `temp.txt` and this is the one that violates the pattern.

Comment: Can you add `print(filename)` as 1st line inside your loop, then launch your script and write what is last filename which was printed before error? This way we would know which filename exactly is problematic.

Comment: Off the top of the head guess: `.` and `..`. But why ask here? Just check the return of `re.match` and print the offending value if it's `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using regex. Using `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    root, _ = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if "_" in root:
        activity, num = root.split("_")
        if activity == "cooking":
            # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

`re.match(pattern, root)` can return None if not matching

1. You can check the result of `re.match(pattern, root) == None` and find the image
2. use `https://regex101.com/` to check your regexp with name of images

Answer (score 1):

If `re.match(pattern, root)` is None then calling `.group(1)` will give you the attribute error. So in certain cases you don't seem to match all entries in your directory.

It's hard to know which ones are giving you problems, but by default `\w` matches only `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so:

- Do any files contain punctuation characters (e.g. %)?
- Do any files contain non-ASCII characters (e.g. ñ)?
- Are there non-dataset related files in the directory as well?

You could post the directory listing, then maybe we can spot the file.